# Not a statement requiring while and other errors

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nata do = new Nata();

    }

}
```

Makes a lot of errors

> C:\Users\Irmantas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\src\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\Test.java:4:
>   error: not a statement
>           Nata do = new Nata(); C:\Users\Irmantas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\src\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\Test.java:4:
>   error: ';' expected
>           Nata do = new Nata(); C:\Users\Irmantas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\src\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\Test.java:4:
>   error: illegal start of expression
>           Nata do = new Nata(); C:\Users\Irmantas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\src\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\Test.java:4:
>   error: while expected
>           Nata do = new Nata(); C:\Users\Irmantas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\src\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\Test.java:8:
>   error: illegal start of expression }
>   C:\Users\Irmantas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\src\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\Test.java:8:
>   error: reached end of file while parsing }
>   C:\Users\Irmantas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\src\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\Test.java:9:
>   error: reached end of file while parsing 7 errors
>   C:\Users\Irmantas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\nbproject\build-impl.xml:929:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\Irmantas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\penkiasdesimtmuzikosatspalviu\nbproject\build-impl.xml:269:
>   Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

where is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't know what Nata is.

Comment: I don't think you can name a local variable with a keyword also...

Comment: `do` is a reserved word, so you cannot name your variable `do`. You could  say `Nata nata = new Nata();`. However, that presumes that the compiler knows about the class `Nata` as @blahfunk noted.

Comment: In NetBeans Ctrl+Shift+I fixes the imports I believe, to import Nata.

Answer (score 0):

`do` is a keyword in Java (used in do-while loops); it cannot be used as a variable name.

Replace with almost anything else:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nata nata = new Nata();
    }
}
```

Provided Nata is visible to the class, this will work.